# CS1503 ArguCannot convert from 'Tes4.GUI.PrintBill.printBill' to 'System.Windows.Forms.Form'

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, report

I have a class for printing (named **prinBill.cs**)

```
using Tes4._3_Tier.DTO;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Tes4.GUI.PrintBill
{
    public partial class printBill : DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.XtraReport
    {

        public printBill()
        {

            InitializeComponent();


        }

        public void InitData(int patient_id, int bill_id, string name_pa, string add, string dob, string sym, string treat, string gender, float Sum,List<bill_ItemDTO> data)
        {
            bill_ID.Value = bill_id;
            patienntID.Value = patient_id;
            patientNName.Value = name_pa;
            patientAdd.Value = add;
            patientTreat.Value = treat;
            patienSym.Value = sym;
            patientDOB.Value = dob;
            Total.Value = Sum;
            patientGender.Value = gender;
            objectDataSource1.DataSource = data;

        }

    }
}
```

I don't know what exactly happened to my code after rebuilding it (My last running was good). Here's the code I got an error in my **printBill.Designer.cs** (**this** argument)

```
this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
this.InitializeComponent();
DevExpress.XtraSplashScreen.SplashScreenManager splashScreenManager1 = new DevExpress.XtraSplashScreen.SplashScreenManager(this, null, true, true);
```

I googled at some topic but it didn't help me at all. I really appreciate your assistance.

Comment: `XtraReport` doesn't inherit from `System.Windows.Form`, so any instances which inherit from `XtraReport` can't be cast to `System.Windows.Form` (in the same way that if I asked you to use a carrot as a credit card, nowhere would accept it).

Comment: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6fqD_spnDhg&t=1543s), I just followed this tutorial. My last debugging was really well, but the next time it got an error. I'm so sorry for asking you solutions.

Comment: I'm not seeing where the line you're having trouble is in the tutorial.

Comment: @LắcLê, Please try to understand John comments, you are trying to inherit XtraReport from Windows Form. There are lot of examples exist for DevExpress website for Xtraprint. Please check DevExpress Demo center Exe in your computer which is installed along with  your devexpress installation. If not Please install relevant version in your system and try.

Comment: I got John's point. @John ,printBill.designer's code is auto-generated.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: But where did you find the code you're using? I can only assume you've done something differently to your tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this line from the designer file:

```
DevExpress.XtraSplashScreen.SplashScreenManager splashScreenManager1 = new DevExpress.XtraSplashScreen.SplashScreenManager(this, null, true, true);
```

The SplashScreenManager constructor overload you're using expects a Form type for the first paramenter. The XtraReport class does not derive from Form, so "this" (an XtraReport) cannot be used:

```
SplashScreenManager(Form parentForm, Type splashFormType, bool useFadeIn, bool useFadeOut)
```

[Source](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraSplashScreen.SplashScreenManager..ctor(nR64hg))

If you want to show a waiting screen as your report builds, do it from the form invoking the report, not from the report itself.

Comment: You saved me! Thank you a bunch @Brendon